# Django only allowing users into their own profile for multiple pages

Tags: django

I have this URL private/profile/<pk> and I wrote something like this to keep any user except the profile owner out of that page

```
if int(pk) != profile:
            return HttpResponse("ERROR:...")
        else:
            return render(...)
```

The problem is that I have multiple urls like "private/profile/pk/editProfile", and I need to write the code above for every single URL.

Is there a better practice for this?

Comment: If profile has a relation to the `User` model you can use `request.user.relation.to.profile` instead of using `pk` in the URL.

Comment: Are you using class based view or function based?

Comment: im using class based views. is it bad practice to include the pk in the url?

Comment: @GonzaloTuñez, not really, everyone does that ! plus you can encrypt it if you are not comfortable with it !

Comment: Still the question is - how do I provide protection against intruders for all urls starting with private/profile/<pk> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AccessMixin

class OwnerOnlyMixin(AccessMixin):
    # you can override this method to handle what you want to do when user is not allowed.
    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return super().handle_no_permission()

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if int(pk) != profile:
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

# example view class
class ProfileView(OwnerOnlyMixin, <... rest of your classes ...>):
    # config for the mixin, if you dont override the method `handle_no_permission`.
    raise_exception = False
    permission_denied_message = '' # if `raise_exception` is True, an exception with this message will be raised
    login_url = reverse('url-name') # if `raise_exception` is False, enter URL you want the user to redirect to

    # rest of your methods
```

You need to create a custom mixin class, which will do the common task of filtering out the non-owners.
You can see that I am using [AccessMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin) as the parent class, you can choose to not use it.